# What is the default expiration of IDistributedCache?

Tags: .net-core

When using `IDistributedCache`, the expiration of the data to be cached can be set by providing a DistributedCacheEntryOptions object through its method `SetAbsoluteExpiration()`.

But when does the cache expire by default in case the DistributedCacheEntryOptions object is not used?

Answer (score 1):

There would be no expiration by default (when persistence is On).

Feel free to try it by running **docker-compose up** using this [app](https://github.com/aignatovich/DotNetCore-Redis-Compose-playground)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this has been changed or if it's dependent on what implementation of `IDistributedCache` you're using but here my take on it:

I use `IDistributedCache` with SQLServer (not the best but that's not the topic here).
`DistributedCacheEntryOptions` is mandatory, so it must be initialized anyway before calling `Set`, `SetAsync` `SetString`, `SetStringAsync`.

If you `new() DistributedCacheEntryOptions` and pass it directly to your function without calling `SetAbsoluteExpiration()`, you'll end up with 20min cache like so:

[image]